# Access violation when writing location

Tags: c, pointers, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

So my code should work this way:
the function gets as input a char**(array of strings) and just char*(string), also int number.
then, I have to realloc the char** to the number, and add to the last pointer in him the string. Here is how I wrote that:

```
void addReason(char** stringsArr, char* string, int number)
{
    stringsArr = (char**)realloc(type, sizeof(char) * number);
    *(stringsArr + number - 1) = (char)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(string));
    strcpy(*(stringsArr + number - 1), string); // the exception thorws here, 
//talking about the *(stringsArr + number - 1) pointer
}
```

Comment: Your size calculation is not correct. You should allocate `sizeof(char *) * number`. That should get rid of the crash, but there's the problem that your allocation will not be reflected in the calling code, where the array still holds a pointer to the (now possibly invalid) old memory.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
stringsArr = (char**)realloc(type, sizeof(char) * number);
```

should be:

```
stringsArr = realloc(stringsArr, sizeof(char *) * number);
```

or even better:

```
stringsArr = realloc(stringsArr, sizeof(*stringsArr) * number);
```

Note the parameter to the `sizeof` operator, and don't cast the return from `realloc` or `malloc`.

Second:

```
*(stringsArr + number - 1) = (char)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(string));
```

should be:

```
stringsArr[number-1] = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
```

`sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so you don't need to specify it. You need to add 1 for the terminating null. Array index notation is generally easier to follow than pointer notation.

Third, on the off-chance that `reason` actually is a valid identifier and not a copy-paste error:

```
strcpy(*(stringsArr + number - 1), reason);
```

should be:

```
strcpy(stringsArr[number - 1], string);
```

As additional points:

1. You should always be checking the return value of `malloc` and friends.
2. All identifiers starting with `str` and a lowercase letter are reserved for the standard library, so your `stringsArr` and `string` are technically illegal identifiers.
3. As noted in the comments, you don't return your new pointer, so you're leaking your new memory here, but since your code clearly doesn't compile anyway, maybe there's more code you're not showing us.

Comment: thank you it worked:)
and about your second note, I know I can do that but this is I suppose to do for my class(I mean they work both ways) so the problem was only in the first line.
p.s, 'reason' should be string, I changed my names to these ones and missed it sorry if it's disappointed you, I already changed it to 'string'.